# Stacking <td> elements not working

Tags: html, css

This seems like it should be pretty simple, and everything works as expected in a local HTML example, but something is messing with my code and I can't figure out what it is.

At the following dev URL (http://mountdoracoffeehouse.weebly.com/test.html) I have a simple `<table>` at the very top of the page. This is just to strip it down to the most basic functionality, the real application will be with other `<table>` elements on the site. The site is built using Weebly's CMS, which unfortunately uses `<table>`'s to create columns. when you view a Weebly site on a mobile device, they load a mobile stylesheet that sets the `<td>` elements to `display:block`, causing them to stack. This is what's not working for me. I am not using Weebly's default mobile stylesheet, and am instead creating my own.

So I have the following HTML structure:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>This is td 1</td>
         <td>This is td 2</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

...and the following CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
   table {
      width:100%;
      table-layout:fixed;
   }
   td {
      width:100%;
      display:block !important;
   }
</style>
```

Can anyone mess with the DOM via Inspector and figure out what is getting in the way of this code working? I'm slamming my head on the desk as I type this after hours of frustration.

Thanks,
~Nathan

Comment: if `display: block` is screwing things up in weebly's style sheets, why are you using it in your own?

Comment: That's not the behavior nor function of the `<td>` element. Consecutive `<td>` elements nested in a table row is supposed to stack against each other horizontally (i.e. side by side). You should look into use `<div>` or the likes (non-table elements). In other words, table elements are a poor choice for layouts.

Comment: The code you provided should stack them, so if they're not stacking then either your CSS isn't being applied, or it's being overridden by other CSS that is being applied later on or is more specific.

Comment: Thank you @j08691...I thought it was right too. I guess I give up until Weebly makes some changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use divs to lay this out rather then table. Have a look at the display options here:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

You can use the table ones to align your divs like a table.

Comment: OP stated that "site is built using Weebly's CMS, which unfortunately uses <table>'s to create columns."  Seems like he doesn't have the option to change that to divs.  This is the "correct" way to do it, though.

Comment: If you must use tables, you need to get rid of the display:block, or, at the very least remove the "!important" that follows it. If you remove the "!important", you would be able to add a class to this table to over-write the display:block on your table.

Comment: @LeoFarmer, I thought the "display:block" was necessary to get <td> elements to stack instead of line up in a row. Is that not the case?

Comment: Hi, if you want your td elements to stack, put them inside row tags. e.g. <tr><td>some text</td></tr>